# Magento 1 problems with PHP 7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

When I try to use Magento 1.x with PHP 7 I am facing these two problems.

Issue 1 :

Can not convert array to string in : `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php`

Issue 2 (While login at admin) :

```
Decoding failed: Syntax error app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php(663): Zend_Json::decode('''', 1)
```

Comment: Do you need to use PHP 7? Magento 1.x is not compatible with PHP 7 and aside from the errors you see there may be many odd unseen ones that may be hard to track down. It may be easier to ask your hosting provider to downgrade to the correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solution for it

1) Use Inchoo_PHP7 module (https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7) but i have noticed in my some projects it makes issue for the cart discount.

2) Handle the issues individually.

Issue 1 Solution:

in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` at Line 555

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

to

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Issue 2 solution:

in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php` at Line 659

```
return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
```

change to

```
return Zend_Json::decode($objectDecodeType);
```

I hope it will save your time. Please vote me if it will help you. Thank you very much.

Comment: What issues in the cart discount did you find when using the Inchoo_PHP7 module?